# TensorFlow knows function exists inside of script before script is executed, how?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am using TensorFlow 2.3 and had a problem with the GPU libraries installed so my scripts were not running. That is not the issue here, instead, the weird thing that happened was the script was not running when a certain TensorFlow function was present inside of the script. For example:

```
# test.py
print('The script has started')
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.Model(...)
model.fit()
```

Whenever the `fit()` function was present, the script would not get executed, not even the print statement at the top; instead, errors were just printed to the console. Yet, once I removed the `fit()` function the script ran completely fine. How does TensorFlow know that the `fit()` function is present within the code? I would normally expect `The script has started` to be printed to the console, and then errors be thrown. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you try again with `print('The script has started', flush=True)` ? It could be that the print buffer has not been flushed yet.

Comment: Oh my gosh, that solved it! I thought I was going insane before, didn't even think of it not flushing out. Thank you!! Post that as an answer and I will mark as solved, @jakub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffer that `sys.stdout` (the default file for [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)) uses is likely not flushed before `model.fit` starts running. You can forcibly flush this buffer with `flush=True`.

```
print('The script has started', flush=True)
```